Hosts file affects other hosts network name resolution
I have a situation where editing the hosts file on a Windows host interferes with another site with tld on the Internet.  The hosts file has one entry of a local IP and a name WITHOUT the TLD.
Devices connected to the Internet router receive err_connection_timeout  when accessing production site gccautos.com on the Internet!
For simplicity, if I put an entry of
192.168.1.10 google
in the hosts file, no one, including devices connected wirelessly to the ISP's router, are able to reach google.com or any site hosted on the same IP there. Instead, they receive CONNECTION TIMED OUT.
Note that the mapping doesn't include the TLD and that the wireless device cannot communicate with the PC hosting the site at all because they are in different segments and no gateway exists between them.
I understand that the hosts file only affects the local machine and not other nodes.
Note also that this strange behavior was nonexistent on previous ISP.  I don't know the differences between their DNS setup.  I tried using Google DNS, but it didn't change anything.
Is there a solution or an explanation for this behavior?
Thanks for your help.

google is a valid TLD.

Is it possible that DNS is being served to your network by your computer?

First, I am still stuck with this mess, but a few things have developed.  This D-Link router frim my new ISP seems to black llists ips momentarily when I try to ftp to them through a wired connection.  Weird conclusion, but it doesn't happen with wireless connections to this D-Link A300 router.
